# Proper way to change out a static page to an "expired page"?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a bunch of static promotional pages. However, if the promo has passed (expired), i need to navigate/show an expired page.  What is the correct way to do this with static pages in NextJS?

Attempt 1: do a check if expired in getStaticProps. Issue, revalidation happens every 600 seconds. So this could happen at 12:28am instead of 12:00am on the dot (depending on when i deployed it).

So it isn't showing an expired page on time. How to fix this issue? Or implement the 'proper' way to change out the page.

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const pageSlugs = await api.getAllSlugs();

  const paths = pageSlugs.map((slug) => (params: {promo: slug})
  );

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: "blocking"
  };
};

export async function getStaticProps({ preview = false, params, previewData }) {
  const page = await api.getSlug(params.promo, {
    preview,
    enviroment: previewData?.enviroment
  });

  const isExpired = checkIfExpired(page.promoStart, page.promoEnd);

  const expiredPage =
   isExpired
      ? await api.getPage("expired-page", {
          preview,
          enviroment: previewData?.enviroment
        })
      : null;


  return {
    props: {
      page,
      isExpired,
      expiredPage,
    },
    revalidate: 600
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the revalidate time dynamically:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ preview = false, params, previewData }) {
  const page = await api.getSlug(params.promo, {
    preview,
    enviroment: previewData?.enviroment
  });

  const isExpired = checkIfExpired(page.promoStart, page.promoEnd);

  const expiredPage =
   isExpired
      ? await api.getPage("expired-page", {
          preview,
          enviroment: previewData?.enviroment
        })
      : null;

 let revalidate = 600
 if (Date.now() <= page.promoStart) {
   revalidate = (page.promoStart - Date.now()) / 1000
 } else if (date.now() > page.promoStart && Date.now() <= page.promoEnd) {
   revalidate = (page.promoEnd - Date.now()) / 1000
 }

  return {
    props: {
      page,
      isExpired,
      expiredPage,
    },
    revalidate
  };
}
```

This assumes `promoEnd` and `promoStart` are date objects but you can adjust as needed. Also make sure server time aligns with the timezone used on the date object.